What's the difference between 生气 and 可气?
Can simeone explain the difference between 生气 and 可气 ?
Thanks!

There are 可惡，可恨 even 可怒也，  But 可气 is not a thing.

@TangHo it's in dictionaries. Maybe it's a regional thing you're not familiar with. 可气〔-氣〕/
kěqì/
形 使人生气/
这孩子天黑了还不回家, 真可气。

It seems to be an uncommon term, judging from a frequency list I encountered - see my answer below.

生气 - angry
可气 - annoying (worth to be angry)

他總是迟到, (真)可气 - He's always late, it is (so) annoying!

可气的是, 他總是迟到 - It is worth to be angry, for he's always late. (Note, "可气的是" can be, and often is, replaced by "值得生气的是".


Expresions similar to 可气: 惱人, 煩人 (可气, 惱人, 煩人 are milder than the expressions - 可惡; 討厭).

生气 means annoyed. 可气 means annoying, i.e., 令人生气. For example, if you have a noisy neighbor, then 你很生气 and 你的邻居很可气.

Grammatically these terms can behave quite differently.

可气: stative verb a.k.a. adjective

生气: noun, stative verb and also verb-object a.k.a separable verb. The latter means that it can be split, giving constructions like the following:


他还在生我的气呢
He is still angry with me.
Here are the CEDICT entries for these two terms.

生氣 生气 [sheng1 qi4] /to get angry; to be furious/vitality; liveliness/
可氣 可气 [ke3 qi4] /annoying/irritating/exasperating/

It also may be useful to note that 生气 is a commonly used word (it's number 819 in a list of Chinese terms sorted by usage frequency I downloaded a while ago called SUBTLEX), whereas 可气 is much less common - (number 45298 in the SUBTLEX list).
As a student of Chinese, I wonder - is there an implicit 生 in 可气?  I.e. does 可气 carry more or less the same meaning as 可生气?

可生气：soooo angry

I don't think it's necessary to imagine an implicit 生 in the word 可气. 气 is quite happy to behave as a verb in its own right (cf. 气死了，别气我了，我气他一下, etc).

What kyc (not KFC?) said:

可气，读音是kě qì。意思是使人生气。
生气 生气是汉语词语，读作shēng
qì，一是指活力，生命力，生机；二是指发怒，因不合心意而不愉快。风水学中将生气简称为气，亦名内气、五气、阴阳之气。

